# WPF Група одинаковых елементов с одним id

Tags: c#, wpf, button, textbox

Например есть поле и 2 кнопки, одна добавляет, каждый раз, после нажатия в поле число, а другая кнопка- убирает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так что бы для каждой кнопки и текстового поля было одно имя?

Comment: Как? Использовать привязки. Одно свойство, которое вы привязываете без имен куда надо и сколько надо.

Comment: Если используете паттерн mvvm, то все верно написали выше - через свойство(каждое поле - новое свойство). На + и - каждой кнопки, например, биндится на одну команду(command), но с разными параметрами (CommandParameter), которые уже +/- разные свойства.

Comment: А контрол NumericUpdown не рассматривали для своей задачи?